# Cycles Render: How to remove accidental gloss/wet?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm still a newb to Blender and even more to Cycles Render but I have a model with mapped textures with nodes set up for transparent textures as well.. however when I make the model Smooth and change from Blender Render to Cycles Render I get on the left side this effect of gloss(?) or wet(?) like in the screen below.

[image]

What do I need to do to get rid of off this effect?

The .blend file of the model
[image]

Comment: It just looks like your texture mapping is messed up.  This is probably due to the fact that you created the materials in BI and then switched to Cycles.  Cycles and BI materials are completely different so you will have to remake the materials in Cycles.  We could help you with that if you could provide a little more detail, like some screenshots of your nodes or, even better, [upload a .blend](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: I uploaded the .blend file and I would be really thankfull if you would tell me what did I wrong because even in Blender Render my mapped texture is messed up :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless misunderstood what you mean it looks like a basic normal problem. All you have to do is recalculate normals to make them all consistent.

Just enter edit mode select all faces of your model and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: Dear lord how newb I am! Thank you very much for helping!